Plotly `kaleido` and `orca` installation issues on Raspberry Pi (ARM64) for exporting static images
I'm trying to use Plotly on my Raspberry Pi (ARM64) to export static images from my figures, but I've run into several issues when trying to use both kaleido and orca as image export engines. Basically the first idea was to simply execute:
fig.write_image("static/mensajes_enviados.png")

But when doing so I was facing the following problem:
Failed to start Kaleido subprocess. Error stream: /home/ivanlosarcos/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kaleido/executable/kaleido: line 10: 29947 Segmentation fault ./bin/kaleido $@
After investigating a bit I read somewhere that kaleido and the arm64 of a RaspberryPi5 do not get along very well, so I tried to use orca.
Steps I've tried:

kaleido Installation:

I attempted to install kaleido using pip install kaleido, and the installation worked perfectly fine but I kept getting the error showed above.


orca Installation (via apt and conda):



After encountering issues with kaleido, I turned to orca as an alternative. I installed it in two ways:

Using apt:
sudo apt install orca


Using conda:
conda install -c plotly plotly-orca




After both installations, I run the command fig.write_image("static/mensajes_enviados.png", engine="orca"), but I get the following error:

The orca executable is required in order to export figures as static images, but the executable that was found at '/usr/local/bin/orca' does not seem to be a valid plotly orca executable. Please refer to the end of this message for details on what went wrong.

Details:

My Raspberry Pi runs on ARM64 architecture.
I have tried reinstalling both orca and kaleido using different methods, but both engines fail to work.
I'm using Plotly for creating interactive charts, and I need a way to export them as PNG or other static images.

What I expect:

I would like to use orca or kaleido (preferably kaleido) for exporting Plotly figures as static images on my Raspberry Pi. However, neither engine seems to work, and the installation for kaleido fails due with the error messagge showed above. For orca, I get the error about an invalid executable.

What I have tried:

Installing orca with apt and conda and checking if the executable is valid. They weren't.
Trying different methods to install kaleido.
Configuring the executable path for orca by updating the environment variables.

My question:

How can I resolve the issue with kaleido installation on ARM64? Is there an ARM64-compatible version available?
Does anybody know if it's event possible to do what I am trying to do? And if so, is this the best method, is there any other methods or engines I could/should use?
How can I fix the orca executable error? Is there a way to make orca work properly on ARM64?

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!
